# Django unit tests ask to delete MariaDB DB: (1007, "Can't create database 'test_x_django'; database exists")

Tags: sql, django, unit-testing, mariadb

I have django unit tests creating a MariaDB database for tests. 
I am accessing the database with a user and password in the settings file and keep getting this error:
`Type 'yes' if you would like to try deleting the test database 'test_x_django', or 'no' to cancel: Got an error creating the test database: (1007, "Can't create database 'test_x_django'; database exists")`

Which makes me type 'yes' every time that I run unit tests - specifically after stopping tests in the middle (not allowing django to delete the database?).

I have tried a lot of solutions, including: trying to use the root user, giving django_user all permissions to 'test_x_django' db, giving django_user permissions to createdb. I have not found a solution online for MariaDB, in this case.

The configuration in my `settings.py` file is:

```
DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.mysql',
        'NAME': 'x_django',
        'USER': 'django_user',
        'PASSWORD': 'xxxx',
        'HOST': 127.0.0.1,
        'PORT': '3306'
    }
}
```

Is there a solution to make django stop asking the question, and delete the Database automatically?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just pass --keepdb option. `python manage.py test --keepdb` if you want to keep it. If you want to destroy it pass --noinput `python manage.py test --noinput`.

See docs https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/topics/testing/overview/#the-test-database

Comment: Thanks. This is not ideal because I don't want the data to continue on living on my computer after running the tests. I would like the datebase to be deleted.

Comment: Sorry I misunderstood at first. I updated my answer.

Comment: --noinput skips the warning and makes sure that the tests work on the existing database. I would like the database to be deleted after or before every test run. I do not want to skip the error, I want the error to not happen. Thanks for trying to help.

Comment: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/topics/testing/overview/#the-test-database docs state that it automatically destroys database.